# Undirected graphs treated as directed in igraph-python

Tags: python, igraph

I have a graph that I create by reading in a GML file.  I'm trying to find all of the edges that touch a node N.  My code is as follows:

```
self.simGraph = Graph.Read_GML(file_name)
node = self.simGraph.vs.find(title=title)
edge_set = self.simGraph.es.select(_source=node.index)
```

I noticed, when debugging, that edge_set would often contain only one edge, but when I changed `_source`to`_target`, I would get a different set of edges.  I tried adding

```
self.simGraph = self.simGraph.as_undirected()
```

but got the same results.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `source` and `target` do not make sense (at least not for igraph) when the graph is undirected as each endpoint of each edge is both a source and a target at the same time. This will be fixed eventually; feel free to follow the corresponding [bug report](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/30) on Github.

Comment: Right, source and target *shouldn't* make sense, which is why I was confused to get different results.  Thanks for the pointer to the bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be getting different sets of edges when you use the current vertex as 'source' or 'target'. It seems like igraph is randomly assigning 'source' and 'target' roles to vertices for undirected networks but it knows that the network is undirected. Even if you generate an undirected network from scratch, the set of edges connected to a vertex will be different when you set that vertex as a source or a target. If you want to get a list of edges (id's) incident on a o vertex i, use the following

```
g.incident(i)
```